# Using matrix of linear operator to solve a differential equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Above is a matrix of a linear operator (on the vector space of polynomials of degree at most 3) relative to the basis,

{${1, x, x^2, x^3}$}

The operator is defined as I - L, where I is the identity matrix and L is the differentiation operator (d/dx).

How can I use this to solve the differential equation,

$y'-y=5x^2-3$

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Write $y = y_0 + y_1 x + y_2 x^2 + y_3 x^3$, which becomes the vector $\vec{y} = [y_0, y_1, y_2, y_3]$. Then the LHS of your equation is $(L-I)\vec{y}$. The RHS of your equation is just $[-3, 0, 5, 0]$. So now you have a simple matrix equation to solve, which is equivalent to your differential equation.